# WinJS - Adding 'selected' style to first item in listview on load

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-store

I'm trying at present to use a listview to drive the content of a separate div in a Windows Store app (HTML/JS).

I have a simple function which I call inside the 'oniteminvoked' handler for my listview.

**Method call**

```
MyApp.Util.addClassById(q(".item"), item.itemId, "selected");
```

(Where item.itemId is that of my newly selected item and 'q' is an alias for WinJS.Utilities.query)

**Method declaration**

```
function addClassById(elements, selectedId, className) {

    elements.forEach(function (el) {

        var id = parseInt(el.attributes['data-id'].value, 10);

        if (id === selectedId) {
            util.addClass(el, className);
        }
        else {
            util.removeClass(el, className);
        }
    });
}
```

This works as expected after my listview is loaded and I'm selecting new items. Where it doesn't load is when I try to call it during my `ready` function for the page in question.

When I go through in debug, it seems that my query for items in the list doesn't return anything during the pages `ready` function, so I'm assuming the list hasn't been rendered at this point and the DOM query returns nothing.

So the question is this, what's the recommended approach to select an item (or perform an action on a listview) after it's been rendered?

I thought they might be an 'afterrender' type event where I could call the function but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know of to do this is to capture the `onloadingstatechanged` event and wait until the ListView has been "loaded". You can see how by visiting my blog post at http://codefoster.com/loadingstates

Comment: I have the same problem trying to select an item in a listview. I can select it with listView.selection.set(index) where index is a number, but how can I find the item I want to programmatically select in the listview?

Comment: After a list has been loaded, you have access to all of the DOM representation, but not the underlying data. The easiest way to id elements is to programmatically add a data- attribute into the dom and then look for that. For instance, if you add data-id="17" in the item, then you can iterate your list (after it's been loaded) and read the data-id values looking for the one you want.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to this question, I think I find a way to iterate through the list items. It would be nice to know if it is an acceptable way because there is not much documentation about this around. thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at this code, it iterate through all the data in the list and compare it with another list to select every element that match an id in the data.

and if you use `element.querySelector` instead of `document.getElementById` you can use this in your ready function.

```
var itemList= [
{ id: "11", name:"value1" }, 
{ id: "12", name:"value2" }
]

    var listView = document.getElementById("listViewOwners").winControl;

    var itemsInFavList = listView.itemDataSource.getCount()._value;
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsInFavList; i++) {
        var item = listView.itemDataSource.itemFromIndex(i);

        if (compareArray(itemList, item._value.data).length > 0)
        {    
            listView.selection.add(item._value.index);
        }
    }
}

//this function uses the filter function to check 
//if the element from the listView is contained in the data list
function compareArray(itemList, data){

    return itemList.lineOwners.filter(
        function (subitem) {
            return subitem.id === data.key
        });
    }
```